# How to align ButtonMenu's menu to the opposite side?

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I'm trying to align the Menu of my `MenuButton` to be flush to the right side of the MenuButton instead of the default left side. I have my MenuButton like so:

```
menubutton("Max Voltage") {
    item("Test 1").action {
        println("test 1 pressed")
    }
    item("Test 2").action {
        println("test 2 pressed")
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of where it is currently aligned vs where I would like it to align:

[image: example]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do this "officially" (either through JavaFX or TornadoFX). It is probably possible through custom drawing of the MenuItem...

Comment: Unfortunate :( I was messing around with trying to change the anchor position of the menu but couldn't quite figure out how it's supposed to be done. I'll keep searching I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Using javafx [MenuButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) This:

```
    MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Eats");

    Label burgerText = new Label("Burger");
    burgerText.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuButton.widthProperty());
    burgerText.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
    MenuItem burger = new MenuItem("", burgerText);

    Label hDogText = new Label("Hot Dog");
    hDogText.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuButton.widthProperty());
    hDogText.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    MenuItem hDog = new MenuItem("",hDogText);
    menuButton.getItems().addAll(burger, hDog);
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't solve the question? The question is about how to align MenuItem with the end of the MenuButton, not how to right-align the Label?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović   The label is a node within  MenuItem. By binding its width and using `.setAlignment` you get the desired look. I am waiting for OP response.

Comment: I can make the menus fit the width of the button using this method, which I will do in the meantime, but it doesn't actually answer the question (rather provides an alternative) so I'm not sure whether I should accept it as an "answer" or not.

Comment: Accepting / up voting is entirely up to you and the value of it for future readers. This method not only fits the width but also aligns to the right.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the menu item text is longer than the MenuButton width this method becomes unusable as the text just becomes cut off. It does not actually align the menu to the right side. I gave it an upvote (my reputation is too low for it to show up) for providing an alternate solution, but I'm still looking for an answer. Thank you!

Comment: " if the menu item text is longer than the MenuButton width" isn't exactly the case in the code I posted ?